# Canopy 1.4.1 Shell suddenly stuck

Tags: python, console, interpreter, canopy, ioerror

I've been using Enthought Canopy 1.4.1 for a while and I've never had problems. Today I launched the program and whatever I do, the console gives me back either nothing or something like:

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/luca/Software/Canopy32/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/eventloops.pyc in process_stream_events()
     46         while stream.getsockopt(zmq.EVENTS) & zmq.POLLIN:
     47             with context():
---> 48                 kernel.do_one_iteration()
        global kernel.do_one_iteration = undefined
     49 
     50     fd = stream.getsockopt(zmq.FD)

/home/luca/Software/Canopy32/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/ipkernel.pyc in do_one_iteration(self=<IPython.kernel.zmq.ipkernel.Kernel object>)
    292         for stream in self.shell_streams:
    293             # handle at most one request per iteration
--> 294             stream.flush(zmq.POLLIN, 1)
         stream.flush = <bound method ZMQStream.flush of <zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object at 0x8e439ac>>
         global zmq.POLLIN = 1
    295             stream.flush(zmq.POLLOUT)
    296 

/home/luca/Software/Canopy32/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.pyc in flush(self=<zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object>, flag=1, limit=1)
        323         int : count of events handled (both send and recv)
        324         """
    --> 325         self._check_closed()
            self._check_closed = <bound method ZMQStream._check_closed of <zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object at 0x8e439ac>>
        326         # unset self._flushed, so callbacks will execute, in case flush has
        327         # already been called this iteration

/home/luca/Software/Canopy32/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.pyc in _check_closed(self=<zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object>)
    490     def _check_closed(self):
    491         if not self.socket:
--> 492             raise IOError("Stream is closed")
        global IOError = undefined
    493     
    494     def _rebuild_io_state(self):

IOError: Stream is closed
```

Even if I do just something as simple as:

```
a = 1
```

it gets stuck and it gives me the previous IOError. Please help, I need it working!

thanks,
Luca

Comment: Have you tried <strike>turning it off and back on again</strike> reinstalling it?

Comment: Hi, I tried to reinstall following steps 3 and 4 from [link](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy) but now when I do "a = 1" it does nothing.

Comment: I've also tried to reinstall everything (following all the steps) but it did not work

Comment: Does it still generate the error?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But it's stuck. I write 'foo' and it does nothing. This is the behaviour it had when I launched the program the first time today. Then, after relaunching the program several times, it started showing the IOError above.

Last thing I did yesterday was trying to install onedrive-d (ubuntu client for onedrive) [link](https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d) something happened. It told me that python-pip and python3 were missing. I didn't install them in order not to mess things up with my Python 2.7.6 and the installation didn't finish.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you did a full uninstall, steps 3 and 4, do you mean this link?: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy

If so, and you still get the error, then you may have created a python file which has the same name as a system library module, which is therefore interfering with python's startup. Look in hour home directory, or in every directory on your PYTHONPATH if any.

Also: look in your environment (type `env` in terminal) for any python-related environment variables that may be interfering, as your "last thing yesterday" install may have broken things on your system.